Getting error at data flow level while extracting data through REST API
I have an ADF pipeline with a REST API call that is supposed to return data in chunks, with a maximum of 100 records per page.
In the below image it is showing until the Set No of pages required activity it is not showing an error when it is passing to the for each loop and into dataflow it is showing an error as mentioned below
"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'YInv': Failure to read most recent page request: DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some(Bad Request), Status code: 400. Please check your request url and body. (url:https://apisandbox.younium.com/Invoices,request body: None, request method: GET)"
Can anyone help resolve this issue?
ADF Pipeline
Dataflow Source Option Image

Hi @AbhayPrasad, Have you got a chance to check the answer below by Amit to add Pagination rules? Hope it may resolve your issue in this post. Thx for your update and wish you happy weekends.

Try following options for pagination rule ( when you are getting data in chunks).
Add Pagination rules:
RFC5988 and set value to true.


We need to extract data from 36 pages. Can this be done without using "$.body.nextPage"?

I have tried using RFC5988 and set the value to true but it still shows the same error message.
